# Visiting Canada with a refugee travel document

Tags: canada, refugees

If I have refugee travel document issued in Kenya, is it possible for me to travel to Canada without visa? Or being refused to grant me a visa?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to apply for a visa:

> [Most refugees or stateless people need a visa to travel to Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-others.asp)

You would still need to meet the basic requirements (and having a refugee travel document would not, in itself, disqualify you from being granted a visa):

> **[Basic travel requirements](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html)**
>
> You must meet some basic requirements to travel to Canada. You must:
>
> - have a valid travel document, like a passport
> - be in good health
> - have no criminal or immigration-related convictions
> - convince an immigration officer that you have ties—such as a job, home, financial assets or family—that will take you back to your home country
> - convince an immigration officer that you will leave Canada at the end of your visit
> - have enough money for your stay. The amount of money you will need depends on how long you will stay and if you will stay in a hotel, or with friends or relatives.
>
> You may also need a [medical exam](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/medical-police/medical-exams.html) and [letter of invitation](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/letter-invitation.html) from someone who lives in Canada.
>
> Some people are not admissible to Canada, which means they are not allowed to enter the country.

Comment: Which for a refugee is impossible to get the "convince an immigration officer that you have ties—such as a job, home, financial assets or family—that will take you back to your home country", but if one interpret "home" as hosting country.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi In this case, it is ties to the country of refuge they will look for.